# На веб-странице появились отступы между блоками, хотя я их не указывал

Tags: html, css

Как убрать отступы между блоками? Свойства padding и margin не работают.

```css
body {
  min-width: 1360px
}

header {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.indent {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-indent: 610px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightskyblue;
}

.banner {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 420px;
  margin: none;
}

.web1 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



<header>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" onMouseOut='getElementyById' (menu1).style.display="none" ; onMouseover="getElementyById" (menu1).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text indent">HOME</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">ABOUT</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu3).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">WORK</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu4).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">PROCESS</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu5).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">SERVICES</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu6).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">TESTIMONIALS</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu7).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">CONTACT</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="banner">
  <h2 class="web1">Web Design and Development</h2>
  <p class="web2">We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Откройте панель разработчика и посмотрите что за отступы где, возможно стили какого-нибудь плагина перебивают, дополнительно для блока задаете обнуление внешних\внутренних отступов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 1360px
}

header {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.indent {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-indent: 610px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightskyblue;
}

.banner {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 420px;
  margin: none;
}
h2{margin: 0;padding: 0;}

.web1 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



<header>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" onMouseOut='getElementyById' (menu1).style.display="none" ; onMouseover="getElementyById" (menu1).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text indent">HOME</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">ABOUT</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu3).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">WORK</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu4).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">PROCESS</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu5).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">SERVICES</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu6).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">TESTIMONIALS</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu7).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">CONTACT</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="banner">
  <h2 class="web1">Web Design and Development</h2>
  <p class="web2">We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



<header>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" onMouseOut='getElementyById' (menu1).style.display="none" ; onMouseover="getElementyById" (menu1).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text indent">HOME</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">ABOUT</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu3).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">WORK</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu4).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">PROCESS</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu5).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">SERVICES</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu6).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">TESTIMONIALS</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu7).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">CONTACT</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="banner">
  <h2 class="web1">Web Design and Development</h2>
  <p class="web2">We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.</p>

</div>
```

```css
body {
  min-width: 1360px
}

header {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.indent {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-indent: 610px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightskyblue;
}

.banner {
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 420px;
  margin: none;
} html

.web1 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

Просто обнули margin, у  класса `.web1`.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/378346)

Comment: он был, надо было просто немного подумать и понять что  в  .web1 надо было вставить ```margin:0px;```

Comment: Если вы хотите предложить подумать, то лучше это делать в комментариях. Ответ же пишется не только для спрашивающего, SO это база данных. Так что лучше, чтобы ответ был ясным и полным.

Comment: Раз уж так то ok!